# Querying mySQL database with dropdown values

Tags: php, mysql

I've got below snippet where `$filter_xx` values are extracted from a dropdown basis user choice.

I'm trying to query the mySQL database with what the user chose to query the database with via dropdown selection.

You will see that there are 4 `$filter_xx` variables and how many of them are set in a given instance is completely random.

The issue is when I use `&&` in the query it checks if all four parameters are true and then throws and output. (Well I know `&&` is suppose to work that way!). I tried replacing all `&&` operators with `||` and had no luck.

How do I search the database with only options selected by the user?

```
    if(isset($filter_brand) || isset($filter_year) || isset($filter_month) || isset($filter_status)) 
         {
          $query = "SELECT * FROM targets WHERE brand='$filter_brand' && startyear='$filter_year' && startmonth='$filter_month' && status='$filter_status' ORDER BY createdon DESC";
          } else {
          $query = "SELECT * FROM targets ORDER BY createdon DESC";
         }
```

Comment: Do you quote the filter variables before putting them into SQL?

Comment: Check each one individually and only append it to the query if it's got a value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try By This

```
$join = "";
//TAKE ONE BLANK VARIBLE THAT JOIN IF VALUE IS SET

if(isset($filter_brand)){
    //IF VALUE ISSET THAN IT ADDED TO QUERY 
    $join .= " AND brand='$filter_brand'";
}

if(isset($filter_year){
    $join .= " AND startyear='$filter_year'";
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM targets WHERE id != '' $join ORDER BY createdon DESC";
```

Comment: Thanks @TarangP, Do you see the way you append `$join = .= ` is right? I'm seeing an error which says `.=` is unexpected.

Comment: its not because `.=` its because i missed semicolon. http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: Where do you suggest the missed semicolon should go on your snippet?

Comment: @TarangP sure it's not the `$join = .=` as well?

Comment: @MohanWijesena `$join .= " AND startyear='$filter_year'"` is missing a semicolon at the end. If you're running this in PHP and getting a syntax error it should tell you the line number

Comment: @ADyson I did change the semicolon there. However the line number like you say tell me that there is a `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.=' `

Comment: I Updated Answer. sorry for silly mistake. I Hope This Helps @MohanWijesena

Comment: @MohanWijesena like I said above already, `$join = .=` was also a problem. And since that was earlier in the code, you'd see that error first.

Comment: @TarangP May be you need to update the missing semicolon on the answer so my acceptance would make sense to another!

Answer (score 1):

When you have several values that must work in a similar manner, use an array together with loop. I am supposing, you are using mysqli, change quoting for PDO if needed.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "pass", "test");
//...

//SQL attr name => name of POST parameter
$filter = array('brand' => 'brand', 'startyear' => 'year', 
                'startmonth' => 'month', 'status' => 'status');

//here we'll store SQL conditions
$sql_filter = array();

foreach($filter as $key => $value)
{
    if (isset($_POST[$value]))
    {
        //use your library function to quote the variable before using it in SQL
        $sql_filter[] = $key . '="'. $mysqli->escape_string($_POST[$value]) . '"';
    }
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM targets ";

if(isset($sql_filter[0]))
{
    $query .= 'WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $sql_filter) . ' ';
}

$query .= 'ORDER BY createdon DESC';
```

Comment: Looks a solid piece however does NO querying the database at all. (I'm saying this as absolutely no output and no errors shown. Funny of course!) Do you see anything requires changing?

Comment: @MohanWijesena check the final string it produces is valid SQL before sending to the DB, and check it makes sense in terms of what you expected it to do, and check there are actually rows in the DB which match the query filters. Also we don't know from your code, but are you checking for mysql errors when you run your queries from PHP?

Comment: Thanks @ADyson Yes I do sanitize and handles errors as appropriate in my local work environment.

Comment: @MohanWijesena Show us the value of $query you get. What query do you expect to get according to parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM targets WHERE 1 ";
$query = isset($filter_brand) ? $query . " AND brand = '".$filter_brand."'" : $query;
$query = isset($filter_year) ? $query . " AND startyear = '".$filter_year."'" : $query;
$query = isset($filter_month) ? $query . " AND startmonth = '".$filter_month."'" : $query;
$query = isset($filter_status) ? $query . " AND status = '".$filter_status."'" : $query;
$query .= " ORDER BY createdon DESC";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM targets';

$flag = 0;
if(isset($filter_brand) ) 
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM targets WHERE brand='$filter_brand'";
    $flag = 1;
}

if(isset($filter_year)) {
    if($flag==1)
        $query .= " &&";
    $query .= " startyear='$filter_year'";
    $flag = 1;
}

if(isset($filter_month)) {
    if($flag==1)
        $query .= " &&";
    $query = " startmonth='$filter_month'";
    $flag = 1;
}

if(isset($filter_status)){
    if($flag==1)
        $query .= " &&";
    $query = " status='$filter_status'";
    $flag = 1;
}

if($flag == 1){
    $query .= " ORDER BY createdon DESC";
} else {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM targets ORDER BY createdon DESC";
}
```